# find: missing argument '-exec' in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'm writing a backup script and I need to delete some files before older than two days so I can make room for new ones.

So I wrote this:

`find /home/core/backup -mtime +2 -type f -exec rm -fv {} \;`

But it returns:

`find: missing argument '-exec'`

This is what I write normally on cli. How can I do the same thing but for bash?

Comment: Is this part of a shell script or something? If so, please show the shebang, the minimal amount of script that will cause the error and also show ***exactly*** how you run it. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you got CRLF line endings in your script. You can use `sed $'s/\r$//' script.sh > script2.sh` for generating a script without them

Comment: Run your whole shell script through http://shellcheck.net, fix any issues it tells you about, and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: Welcome, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].